# Reverse engineer 4 hex values to DateTime

Tags: datetime, timestamp, hex, decimal, reverse-engineering

Trying to reverse engineer 4 hex values to DateTime stamp from my heating system

I know that:

`5F:A2:30:77 --> 2019.03-10 - 10:08
6D:A2:30:77 --> 2019.03-10 - 10:21`

My first guess was that this was Unix timestamp, so converted the HEX to DEC and to a 32bit int = >

`5F:A2:30:77 -> 1999675999 equivalent to 2033-05-14T09:33:19+00:00 in ISO 8601
6D:A2:30:77 -> 1999676013 equivalent to 2033-05-14T09:33:33+00:00 in ISO 8601`

but unfortunately this does not work

hope that something has a good idea of how to convert this.

Thanks

//Kim

Comment: There's not enough information here to be helpful.  What kind of heating system? Is there an API? How do you know the values you have are timestamps and not something else?  How do you know they are equivalent to those dates and times?  At first glance, only the first segment has changed, which leads me to think if they *are* timestamps then the smaller portion is at the front.  But `6D`-`5F` is 14 seconds difference, not the 13 seconds in the corresponding values.  So do you know those are the *exact* values? Or are they approximations?

Comment: It's also entirely possible that the system keeps an arbitrary number of some time unit (seconds, etc.) since startup, and the date/time at startup is stored somewhere else and thus not conveyed in these values.

Comment: Hi Matt.

The system does not matter, but it is a Vølund PB100 pellet boiler.
Those who have made the controller for the boiler have their own online system, but this work really bad and therefore are we some guys that are making our own :-)

Yes, I know there is 14 in difference, but expect that the system just round up the value.

I'm pretty sure it's not arbitrary system.



Here is a picture.
http://imgbox.com/UXclSYXS

Comment: There's a stack-exchange for reverse engineering, if that helps. Consider a cross post maybe? The question is equally suitable for either.

Comment: The image doesn't help, but if you have more examples from different dates and times, that would.  There's just not enough here to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have solved the riddle of this conversion :-).

```
byte 1 = Minutes after midnight.
byte 2 = Day of the month.
byte 3 = Month.
byte 4 = Number of years since 1900.

# 2019.03.10 19:38
stamp = int(0x7730A49A)
time = stamp & 0b111111111111
hours = int(time/60)
minutes = time - (hours*60)
day = (stamp >> 12) & 0xFF
month = (stamp >> 20) & 0xF
year = (stamp >> 24) + 1900
```

Thanks to all who try to help.

Case closed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got some more alarms to work with.

```
1) 20:32:30:77 --> 2019-03-03 - 09:05
2) 27:32:30:77 --> 2019-03-03 - 09:11
3) 5F:A2:30:77 --> 2019.03-10 - 10:08
4) 6D:A2:30:77 --> 2019.03-10 - 10:21
5) 9A:A4:30:77 --> 2019-03-10 - 19:38
6) 9B:A4:30:77 --> 2019-03-10 - 19:39

X) X1:X2:X3:X4

X1 = are minutes, This is easy to see from the values I have.
```

But how is the rest work together and how is it converted to date/time...?

I'm pretty sure that one must read the bytes backwards

If I convert #3 & #5 from Hex to DEC

```
3) 77:30:A2:5F -> 1999675999
5) 77:30:A4:9A -> 1999676570
this gives a difference of '571' and The time frame is 9 hours, 30 minutes,
which results in 570 minutes.
```

Comment: It seems to me as a number of minutes since some date.

Answer (score 0):

77:30:A2:5F -> 1999675999
5) 77:30:A4:9A -> 1999676570
this gives a difference of '571' and The time frame is 9 hours, 30 minutes,
which results in 570 minutes.
shareimprove this answer